# problems deploying a maven application with mvn command

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven application under eclipse . The jsp pages and WEB-INF folder are located under the path NomeMiaApplicazione\src\main\webapp. I run these commands : mvn clean , 
mvn eclipse: eclipse and mvn compile under the root folder of the application, and in all three cases, the build is successful. However when I access the folder ( into the workspace )
. metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\NomeMiaApplicazione
, there are no jsp pages . what would be the solution for this problem ? thks !

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to clarify the role of the commands you used and their impact on Eclipse.

The `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command creates the Eclipse project files, in order to save you the hassle of configuring a new project and identifying all the sources for it. This command is also equivalent to creating a new Eclipse project from an existing Maven project using the [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) Eclipse plugin. See also [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) regarding the `eclipse:eclipse` command. That being said, you only need to run such command once, and then import the resulting project into Eclipse.

Secondarily, `mvn compile` builds your source files into the `target` directory of your `NomeMiaApplicazione` root folder. This command does not involve Eclipse in any way. Also, web resources are still not packaged.  To package them, you need to issue `mvn package`: you will then find the `<artifact>-<version>.war` file again under `target`, and the pre-packaged content under `target\<artifact>-<version>`. Beware that, in order to account for the `webapp` content, your Maven packaging must be of type `war`. Check the `pom.xml` for the `<packaging>` tag.

Finally, deployment is still another issue. If you actually need to move your `.war` file from the target directory to somewhere else (namely, an autodeploy folder of a servlet container), you can configure the [Maven Deploy Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) and issue `mvn deploy`. I'd rather suggest you to search SO for [deploy war eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deploy%20war%20eclipse) and/or [deploy war maven](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deploy%20war%20maven), since there's plenty of related stuff. In the first case, you will find how to use Eclipse as a facility for deployment, while the second case leverages the command line to provide a more portable/flexible deployment procedure.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `mvn compile` ends on `compile` phase of Maven's default lifecycle. Do `mvn package` and check then. And by the way, default Maven output directory is `target` so rather check it instead of kind of WTP temporary dirs.